# Is it possible to automate pre-installed android apps such as Gallery, Clock, etc. using Selendroid?

Tags: android, automation, selendroid

I am using Selendroid(and a Perl script) and want to know if it's possible to automate pre-installed android apps such as Gallery, Clock, etc. using Selendroid?

Comment: what does your script look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Appium with Selendroid to automate a system app in Android. Use UI Automator viewer and adb logcat to get the application details and objects.

You need to provide the application name and the activity for all applications in Appium, where as you only need to provide the apk file for Selendroid